# PHP Docker app throwing error when submitting data to the database

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and I am trying to dockerise a simple php registration app.  When the credentials are hardcoded into the database connection file the application works as it should.  However i introduced a .env file into the mix to store the credentials and since then i am getting an error whenever i click submit.  Below are my code snippets:

**Docker Compose**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    env_file:
      - ./env/mysql.env

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: webappdb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/fikradev/dbvolume:/home/app
    env_file:
      - ./env/mysql.env

  monitor:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1

volumes:
  db:
```

**.env file contents**

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=@dbuser
MYSQL_DATABASE=issuetrackdb
MYSQL_USER=dbuser
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
```

**dbconnect php file**

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('webappdb', '${MYSQL_USER}', '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}', '${MYSQL_DATABASE}');

if($conn == false){
    die("ERROR - Could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

**This is the error i am getting**

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user '${MYSQL_USER}'@'172.31.0.3' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/dbconnect.php on line 2
ERROR - Could not connect: Access denied for user '${MYSQL_USER}'@'172.31.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

I have been on this for hours.  Grateful if someone could point out where i am going wrong.

Comment: The error show that the ip is `172.31.0.3` but your are trying to connect to `webappdb`. There is something strange here.

Comment: Variables are not interpolated in single-quoted strings. You can see in the error message that php is trying to log into the database with the literal username `${MYSQL_USER}`. Either use double-quoted strings or use the variables directly.

Comment: Thank you.  I will now check and provide an update.

Comment: @sensorario it is only when i use the .env file that this happens.  If i hardode the credentials into the dbconnect file whilst still using webapp it works perfectly.  I do not have much knowledge of .env files and that is where i think the issue is.

Comment: The IP is irrelevant to your issue. That is just the error message thrown by the MySQL server. It's saying *`User '${MYSQL_USER}' is not allowed to connect from 172.31.0.3 using the given password`*. It is unrelated to the way you are connecting *to* MySQL *from* PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting a `.env` file in `docker-compose.yml`, you are providing variables to the *environment* your PHP application is running in. These are *not* automatically made available as variables in your PHP script. You can use `getenv()` to retrieve them:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('webappdb', getenv('MYSQL_USER'), getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'), getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE'));
```